# I want to combine my rsa.public with my rsa.private to a .pfx that I can use to digitally sign an xml file

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, certificate-authority

Here is the code I have so far:

for the private key:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa.private 1024
```

for the public key:

```
openssl rsa -in rsa.private -out rsa.public -pubout -outform PEM
```

Then I'm trying to generate a cert with OpenSSL with the proper X.509 extensions in order to pack it into a PFX/PKCS12 file:

```
openssl req -key .ssh/id_rsa -new -x509 -days 730 -out .ssh/id_rsa.crt
```

And I receive this error:

```
req: Use -help for summary. 
error in req
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Conceptually, I just want to create a .pfx with private key file + public file not using a domain name so that I may digitally sign a file. Do not want a password with the .pfx file.

Answer (score 1):

You create a PKCS12 file with `openssl pkcs12`, like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in rsa.public -inkey rsa.private -export -password pass: -out rsa.pfx
```

THe `-password pass:` means an empty password. See the manual pages for pkcs12 and openssl.